# When typing a generic function, can the return type be omitted?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a general function definition for a 'service' function which will always accept two arguments:

- `context` - this will be the same structure for every function.
- `params` - this will be different each time, and will be typed using a generic.

Since each service function is different, instead of writing out the return type for the function, I'd prefer TypeScript to infer the return type according to the function body. However, I can't figure out how to tell TypeScript to do this when using an Interface Function type.

Here's what I'd like to be able to do:

```
// authenticate.service.ts
export const authenticate: ServiceFn<{
  bearerToken: string;
}> = async (context, params) => {
  context.logger.debug(`Fetching user with bearerToken: ${params.bearerToken}`);

  const user = await UserModel.query().findByToken(params.bearerToken);

  context.logger.debug(`Found user: ${user}`);
  
  return user;
}

// authentication.middleware.ts
import { authenticate } from '@/services/authenticate.service';

export const middleware: RequestHandler = async (req, res, next) {
  const bearerToken = req.header('authorization')?.replace(/^Bearer\s+/i, '');
  if (!bearerToken) {
    throw new Error('No bearer token');
  }
    
  const user = await authenticate({
    context: {
      logger: req.log,
    },
    params: {
      bearerToken,
    },
  });

  // At this point, I'd like TypeScript to infer that user is of type 'UserModel'.
  req.user = user;
  
  next();
};
```

I've tried the following typings, all are resulting in errors.

```
// Causes `user` to be typed directly as `any`
interface ServiceFn<T> {
  (context: Context, params: T): any;
}

// Causes `user` to be typed directly as `unknown`
interface ServiceFn<T> {
  (context: Context, params: T): unknown;
}

// Requires the return type to be passed in to the generic
interface ServiceFn<T, U> {
  (context: Context, params: T): U;
}

// Results in the following error:
// Type 'Promise<UserModel>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<U>'.
//    Type 'UserModel' is not assignable to type 'U'.
//      'U' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'UserModel'
interface ServiceFn<T> {
  <U>(context: Context, params: T): U | Promise<U>;
}
```

Is there anything I can do to achieve this goal?

Comment: The example does not add up, where is the `authenticate` you import and use?

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up, I’ve updated the code to use the correct function name. 

Answer (score 0):

When writing a function like this

```
const authenticateService: Service<T> = function(...) {...}
```

it would be sufficiant to remove the type declaration to make typescript infer all types. What you are telling the compiler here is: dont infer what you would, instead use my more generic type. Which would be usefull in cases like:

```
let o: {
  a: string,
  b?: string
} = {
  a: "qwe",
  b: "qwe"
}

// later

o = {
  a: "eee"
}
```

which would be infered less generic and thus error.

---

However if you want to get this function as say a parameter and you need the infered return type, you could to this:

```
type Context = number

type ServiceFn<T> = (context: Context, params: T) => any;


function giveMeService<InferedService extends ServiceFn<boolean>>(service: InferedService): ReturnType<InferedService> {
  return service(2, true)
}

function exampleService<T>(context: Context, params: T) {
  return "qwe"
}
let str = giveMeService(exampleService)
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gO2BAHsKBeKCCuBbAIwgCcAoU0SKAZRIDcBLAYwgDEEAeAFQD5MoAFE0TI0ALlgjUwADRQwAQ2IK8AZwlcAlJj4KEIANzlSAMxwImwBoigBzBnQgBZCLWKMWHAJIITJCAAmbh7Q0hAIAao09MxsnARwcAA2EHo8PAKqMSwSPn7EgcGxmhIAShDAOMQIXOAQ3r7+QdkQfADepFBQBZXVUFnusQIATHLAxDgQmqQAvuRmFlY2qCpgKUWevEJS4pJI0nKKymoa2h1dPVUIUABEAI4A7hA3s6Qp6Krj-PaOLhsQAhWeDWrha01IQA)

> Note that you have to declare the return type of giveMeService explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. > Note that you have to declare the return type of giveMeService explicitly. - this is exactly what I'm trying to avoid - I'd like to type the arguments of the function using an interface (i.e. type the entire function at once, rather than the arguments individually), but have TypeScript infer the return type.